# Jquery delay after click, to allow different choice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've added a snippet of code with what I am wanting to achieve in the comments.

There are 9 buttons and I need the data-id value of a button that is clicked but the user may click a button, and then quickly decide they want to click a different button, so I would want the value of the last button they click.

```
$( '#add-shot a.btn' ).on( 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // delay for 1500
    // if no other button is clicked, then simply use $( this ).data('id');
    // else, 
    // if other button is clicked, don't use original data-id but use the new data-id

    var id = $( this ).data('id');
    // run the rest of the code

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a global timer with `setTimeout()`. On each click simply clear the timeout, if none of them are clicked within 1.5 seconds then the anonymous  function will be called and get the appropriate `id`:

```js
var timer;

$( 'button' ).on( 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = this;
    clearTimeout(timer);                // Reset the timer.
    timer = setTimeout(function(){      // Call this function if the timer 
     var id = $( self ).data('id');  // did not reset within 1.5 seconds.
        alert(id);
    }, 1500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-id="foo">
 foo
</button>
<button data-id="bar">
 bar
</button>
<button data-id="biz">
 biz
</button>
```